# How do I save bytearray on the server via php?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using simple as3+php, no FMS or such in between. I am making a video recording app, and I can capture frames and convert them to flv encoded bytearray. But the problem happens when I try to save it on the server. If I convert the bytearray to a string via base64 encode and then send that string to the server, all works ok, but the problem is that since it's an video file, it can be pretty big, like 20mb or so, and hence it takes a long time to encode it and then upload it, moreover normally a script timeout will occur during the encoding. To make things faster, I am trying to send the bytearray directly, but my firebug net panel shows me that the data being sent is around 20-46 bytes. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
//var encoded_str = Base64.encodeByteArray(_baFlvEncoder.byteArray);
            //Handle Upload
            /*var url_data:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            url_data.data = _baFlvEncoder.byteArray;*/
            var url_ref:URLRequest = new URLRequest("save_vid.php");

            url_ref.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
            url_ref.data = _baFlvEncoder.byteArray;//url_data;
            url_ref.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

            // just making sure the server knows we are sending data in proper format
            //urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;

            try {
                urlLoader.load( url_ref );
            } catch (e:Error) {
                trace(e);
            }
```

And my PHP code:

```
<?php
echo 'Data:<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
//$decodedData= base64_decode($GLOBALS[ 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' ]);
//file_put_contents("test.flv",$decodedData);
file_put_contents("test.flv",$GLOBALS[ 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' ]);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [`URLRequest.data` documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#data), it specifies the option of using a ByteArray directly.

Here,

```
urlLoader.data = _baFlvEncoder.byteArray;
```

You can then skip the `URLVariables` object, which relies on encoding your transmitted data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is not well suited to binary data (even if it were handled properly, which it may not be).

Comment: ooh thanks, I didn't know about that. This time, though it seems the data is being sent, the video file isn't being generated....I am getting 0kb flv file.

Comment: Not sure if your PHP code is still as shown above--you clearly wouldn't want to base64_decode this input.  @Adam's suggestion here looks reasonable, but I'm not a PHP person.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you should use this for raw data input:

```
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: Thank you both, I wish I could select both the answers....but really, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I was stacked with similar problem for few days, and released that ONLY base64 encode/decode solves this. Similar symptoms just few bytes goes etc. So just go into base64 "direction" to solve this